# Parameter format not matched using attrib in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

```
C:\Windows\system32>attrib -r +s C:\Users\me\Desktop\folder_name
Parameter format not correct -
```

I want to remove the read-only attribute off from the folder.

What is going on? I got this command off Microsoft website.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326549

Thank you !

Comment: What error are you getting? something like `not resetting system file` ?

Comment: @Raystafarian it is stated in the body. "Parameter format not correct " Thank you.

Comment: If there are spaces in your path, you need to surround it in double quotes.

Comment: That solved my problem. You should make it an answer, Ray. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try
`attrib -r +s "C:\\Users\me\Desktop\folder_name"`
If there are spaces in your path you need to surround it with double quotes